# adding header parameteres to HttpClient in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I have this class which registers httpClient and all dependencies in my application .

```
public static class InternalAdminServiceRegister
{
    public const string DefaultConfigSectionName = "InternalApisOptions:Admin";

    public static IServiceCollection AddAdminInternalServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        string configSectionName = DefaultConfigSectionName)
    {
        services.Configure<AdminOptions>(configuration.GetSection(configSectionName));
        services.AddHttpClient<IInternalAdminService, InternalAdminService>((sp, client) =>
        {
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AdminOptions>>().Value;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(options.ServiceUrl);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(options.TimeoutMs);
        }).AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
        return services;
    }

    private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
        => HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 5, durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));

}
```

As you can see I have a httpclient in my class .I want to pass a header parameter from `program.cs`

```
var builder = MtsHost.CreateWebApplication(args);
builder.Services.AddAdminInternalServices(builder.Configuration);
```

I think the best solution is using AddHttpMessageHandler as a parameter in constructor .but I don't know how can I use that

My solution but I think it is not the best solution

```
public static class InternalAdminServiceRegister
{
    public const string DefaultConfigSectionName = "InternalApisOptions:Admin";

    public static IServiceCollection AddAdminInternalServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        string configSectionName = DefaultConfigSectionName,string endpointService="")
    {
        services.Configure<AdminOptions>(configuration.GetSection(configSectionName));
        services.AddHttpClient<IInternalAdminService, InternalAdminService>((sp, client) =>
        {
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AdminOptions>>().Value;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(options.ServiceUrl);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(options.TimeoutMs);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointService)) client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(endpointService, "true") ;
        }).AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
     
        return services;
    }

    private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
        => HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 5, durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));

}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a function to the `AddAdminInternalServices` which is passed to the `AddHttpMessageHandler` call? If so, you need a parameter like this `Func<DelegatingHandler>` or this `Func<IServiceProvider, DelegatingHandler>`

Answer (score -1):

For adding headers, the following method works.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://localhost:7171/identity");
        request.Headers.Add("header1", "value1");    //add headers
        request.Headers.Add("header2", "value2");

        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

For using client, you need register service in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

And inject Httpclient in your class to use

```
public class InternalAdminServiceRegister
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public InternalAdminServiceRegister(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this._client = httpClient;
        }
    }
```